# mitochondria has more activity or the numbers of them are more?

Tags: cell-biology, metabolism, mitochondria

If a cell is needing energy more than the other cells, does it mean that it has more mitochondria or the activity of them is more?

Comment: This [question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/1089/how-is-the-number-of-mitochondria-in-a-cell-regulated?) would seem to be related, although the accepted answer there does not provide supporting references. As part of your own attempt to answer this question, you might consult a cell biology text and look at images of cells with different oxidative metabolic activity to see whether the number of mitochondria varies.

Comment: You might also want to look into condensed and orthodox states of mitochondria. When ATP requirements are high mitochondria will change their state from orthodox to condensed. Condensed state is considered to be the active state.